# Importing large microsoft access (2016) tables with Georgian characters to R

Tags: r, ms-access, large-files, georgian

I have a large data base in Microsoft Access (2016) where some variables contain Georgian characters. I need to import the data tables into R and have done that with the odbcConnect command.It works fine, however, the Georgian letters are not displayed properly but appears as "??????" in R. I guess this is an encoding problem and have spent 2 days browsing the web for solutions but are not even near to find one. I have tried to set the encoding to UTF-8 in R and the local language settings to Georgian (Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "georgian"), however it does not help, even though it seems to work for other foreign characters, such as chinese and russian letters.  Any suggestions?

If I export the Access file to Excel first and then import it into R, it works fine, however, my dataset is so large that I then need to do it piecewise because of the upper limit of ~65000 rows in excel/tab-delimited files if I tick the box "Export data with formatting and layout" in Access which needs to be ticked, otherwise I loose the Georgian characters.

Anyone that have approached the same problem with microsoft access and know how to get around it? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

I am sorry if I have missed out of any questions that have the solution for my problem. I am not a programmer and have never been dealing with these kinds of problems before so this is a real challenge for me.

Many thanks in advance,

Charlotta Rylander

Comment: Which font is R using to display the characters?  Not all fonts include Unicode.  For example, the VBA Editor does not display Unicode characters internally (since it's using a `Courier` font), but can programmatically display them elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer.I think it is "Lucinda Console" in R Studio which I am using. This can be changed though. However, as it desplays Georgian letters if I import an excel file, it do not think this is the problem.

Comment: Did you use the *DBMSencoding = "UTF-8"* argument in `odbcConnect`  call? In fact, please show attempted code. Also, since Excel route worked, consider exporting the files to csv (no limited row limit), then import to R. Access files has a 2 GB limit, so data should not be too much for R.

Comment: Yes, I have used the DBMSencoding="UTF-8" in the odbcConnect call, however I get an error message. Here is the code:`library(RODBC)
gbr<-odbcConnect("GBR2017", DBMSencoding="UTM-8") data<-sqlFetch(gbr,sqtable="dbo_Hospitalizations")                           Error in iconv(data[[i]], from = enc) : 
  unsupported conversion from 'UTM-8' to '' in codepage 1252` If I leave out the DBMSencoding it works fine without error message, however the Georgian letters are replaced by "???????".

Comment: I have tried to export the database tables to a .csv file through the "External data"-> text file, but it has the same maximun number of rows as if I export to excel as I tick the "Export data with formatting and layout" option to keep the Georgian letters. Is there another way to export to .csv?

Comment: What is *UTM-8*? Did you attempt *UTF-8*?

Comment: Sorry, a typo that I did not see. If I correct it to UTF-8, I get no error message but the Georgian letters are still displayed as "???????". Thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: Is your machine running R and MS Access currently set to Georgian language/region? Try doing so via control panel. Also, what version of MS Office do you have as the ~65,000 (2^16) rows is a previous limit. Excel's limit is now 2^20, over 1 million.